# Android to SQL Server?

Tags: android, sql

I have SQL server running on a computer on a local network, which is accessed directly by other computers on the LAN.

Would it be possible to develop an android interface that can retrieve information from this machine?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the JDBC framework.Here is the "getting started" from the official documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/GettingStartedTOC.fm.html

JDBC is part of the base of Java language (Package java.sql) it allows you to connect to a database and perform query vith a total abstraction of the network layer.